# Error running sfdx force:package:list

Tags: salesforcedx, unlocked-package

Please help, I'm getting errors with the sfdx package list and package version report commands. Other sfdx commands are working fine.

```
ERROR running force:package:list: 
NamespacePrefix, ContainerOptions, IsOrgDependent, ConvertedFromPackageId
                                   ^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:87
No such column 'IsOrgDependent' on entity 'Package2'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.
```

Also with version report

```
ERROR running force:package:version:report: 
PatchVersion, BuildNumber, IsReleased, ConvertedFromVersionId, Package2.IsOrgDependent
                                       ^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:182
No such column 'ConvertedFromVersionId' on entity 'Package2Version'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.
```

Comment: Can you post the full command you're trying to execute?

Comment: I executed the same command it got working for me. Can you pls execute the command specifying `--targetdevhubusername` also check second generation packaging is enabled in your production org.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. The full command is:"sfdx force:package:list"

Comment: I tried adding --targetdevhubusername <dev hub name> as suggested, but still got an error. Also tried, uninstall then install of SF CLI and VS Code extension. Still same error. We have several users in our Org that have the same permissions and profile as mine but they don't encounter the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this working once the SFDX cache is deleted. thank you for the responses!

Comment: How do you do that?

Comment: By deleting the .sfdx folder in C:/Users/<username>/

Comment: Just a warning that removing that cache also clears the records of any scratch orgs you are connected to, and possibly other things. So probably wise to make a backup

Answer (score 0):

This is due to an out of date API Version. If you don't want to erase your entire cache, go into your SFDX cache (C:/Users/youruser/.sfdx on Windows) and update your DevHub JSON file (ex. `chris.matos@devhub.com.json`) and update `"instanceApiVersion`" to be a more up-to-date version (ex. I updated mine from 42.0 to 54.0)