# Error Running sfdx force:org:package commands

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

I am having issues running any of the package related commands through the command line.

This came up kind of randomly after it was working a few weeks ago. I have deleted my .sfdx folder in my users directory as was recommended [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/316108/error-running-sfdx-forcepackagelist) but to no avail.

The specific command I am trying to run in the simplest case is

```
sfdx force:package:version:list
```

and the error I get is

```
ERROR running force:package:version:list:  No such column 'Id' on entity 'User'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.
```

I have run sfdx force:org:list and can see that my partner org is listed here, but no matter how many times I authorize this org I am unable to see the package list.

The other rather strange thing is that I am able to deploy packages to my scratch orgs, for instance if I run the command

```
 sfdx force:package:install --package "04t4x000000hwArAAI" --targetusername authorizedOrg --wait 10 --publishwait 10 --json
```

I am able to deploy the package successfully, but I am unable to actually see the list of packages to try to see them or create new ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an [issue](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/1321) reported on the GitHub repo for SFDX. The current solution is to install/downgrade to version 7.120.

If you use npm, the command is:

```
npm i -g sfdx-cli@7.120
```

If you use a binary installer, you can download an older version from [this link](https://sfdc.co/install-older-cli-versions).